# This code is supposed to only allow user to be authenticated if accountVerified is equal to 1, but it still allows user to be authenticated otherwise

Tags: functions, login, forms, sql

```
 global $user_id;
    global $wpdb;
    if(is_user_logged_in()){
        header("Location:https://www.recovermenow.co.uk");

    } 
    if(!$user_id){
        if($_POST){
        
        $username = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        
        $login_data = array();
        $login_data['user_login'] = $_POST['email'];
        $login_data['user_password'] = $_POST['password'];

        $user = wp_signon( $login_data, false);
        
        echo var_dump($user);
        
        if ( is_wp_error($user) ) {
            echo $user->get_error_message();
        } else {   
             wp_set_auth_cookie($user->ID, true);
            header("Location:https://www.recovermenow.co.uk/");
        }
    
        
        

    } else{
        
        echo "
                <html>
                <body>
                <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
                <script type='text/javascript' src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places&key=AIzaSyD-q6DH3L2eG9pzQYxUZ9YzIzIuJbqJAGU&ver=3.exp'></script>


                <div class='container-fluid' id='grad1'>

                    <div class='row justify-content-center mt-0'>
                        <div class='col-11 col-sm-9 col-md-7 col-lg-6 text-center p-0 mt-3 mb-2'>
                            <div class='card px-0 pt-4 pb-0 mt-3 mb-3'>


                                <div class='row'>

                                        <form id='loginform' method='post' action=''>
                                            <fieldset>
                                                <div class='form-card'>


                                    <label>Username</label>

                                   <input 
                                    id='username' 
                                    placeholder='Please enter your email'
                                    type='text' 
                                    class='form-control' 
                                    name='email'/>

                                   <label>Password</label>

                                <input 
                                    type='password' 
                                    class='password' 
                                    name='password' 
                                    class='form-control' 
                                    placeholder='Enter password' 
                                    id='password'/> 

                                    <input 
                                    type='submit' 
                                    name='loginButton' 
                                    id='loginButton'
                                    value='Login'/> 
                                            </div> 


                                            </fieldset>
                                        </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <a id='forgottenPassword' href='forgottenPassword'>Forgotten Password?</a>
                        <a id='registration' href='registration'>Click here to sign up</a>
                    </div>
                    
                </div>
                

                </body>
                </html>";
        
    }
    
} else{
    header("Location:https://www.recovermenow.co.uk/");
}
 





function isUserActivated($username){
    // First need to get the user object
    $user = get_user_by('login', $username);

    if(!$user) {
        $userID = $user->ID;
        if(!$user) {
            echo $user;
           return $username;
        }
    }

    $userStatus = get_user_meta($user->ID, 'Account Verified', true);

    //for testing $userStatus = 1;
    $login_page  = home_url('/log-in-failed/');
    if($userStatus!= 1){
        wp_redirect($login_page);
        echo "Not verified";
        return 0;
        exit;
    }

}

add_action('wp_authenticate', 'isUserActivated');
```

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/402883/edit) to tell us what your question actually is. What *specific* problem are you having?

Comment: Done what we requested above.